# How to move D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 declaration to header

Tags: c++, directx

I am failing to move the following declaration to my C++ Header:

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vertexFormat[] =
{
{0,  0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION,0},
{0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD,0},
{0, 20, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_NORMAL,0},
{0, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TANGENT,  0},
{0, 44, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_BINORMAL, 0}, 
{1, 0,  D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 1},
{1, 16, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 2},
{1, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 3},
{1, 48, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 4},
 D3DDECL_END()
};
```

What is the problem there? How can I resolve this?
Google shows me one interesting result (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/551682-about-d3dvertexelement9/), but somehow I still fail to compile it :(

To be clear - I want to use vertexFormat as a member of my class.

Comment: The problem is that you don't do it right. Start by boiling the situation down to an absolute minimal example that performs what you want to do in a representative fashion (e.g. an array of two ints), and see if you can make *that* work. No point doing D3D if you're still learning the fundamentals of C++. Feel free to post any questions that arise.

Comment: I am fully aware that this is a fundamental C++ issue. My Header contains D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vertexFormat[10]; now and my cpp contains a pretty ugly separate declaration of each value like D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 t1 = {...}; followed by vertexFormat[0] = t1; However, this is a very ugly solution and I am desperately looking for a better way. Can you help me out with the proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm sure you're just missing out something simple, like not declaring extern in the header and implementing in the cpp file. But it's totally impossible to use this huge blob as an example, which is why I suggested that you figure this out first in principle with a very small array. Once you nail that, you can just copy/paste your huge array here.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998207/defining-global-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach I used which could be useful is to provide the implementation in one cpp file:
(**My example uses DirectX10, but for this answer the dx version is irrelevant*)

(.h) Header:

```
int getLayoutPosTexNormCInstancedSize();
D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC* getLayoutPosTexNormCInstanced();
```

(.cpp) Implentation:

```
D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layoutPosTexNormCInstanced[] = 
{
{"POSITION",     0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0,  0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"TEXCOORD",     0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,       0, 12, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"NORMAL",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 20, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"TANGENT",      0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 32, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"BINORMAL",     0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 44, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"BLENDINDICES", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SINT,      0, 56, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }, //4
{"mTransform",   0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1,  0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
{"mTransform",   1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 16, D3D10_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
{"mTransform",   2, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 32, D3D10_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
{"mTransform",   3, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 48, D3D10_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
};


D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC* getLayoutPosTexNormCInstanced() { return layoutPosTexNormCInstanced; }
int getLayoutPosTexNormCInstancedSize() { return sizeof(layoutPosTexNormCInstanced) / sizeof(D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC); }
```

Then at least where you reference or require the input layout when creating your vertex buffer(s), you can simply call the getLayoutPosTexNormCInstanced function, and these can also easily be moved to a class/struct, or even be provided by a reusable module, like a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you simply forgot the "static" key word before your declaration?

```
static D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vertexFormat[] =
{
{0,  0, .......
```

Or in a class:

D3DWhatever.h

```
class D3DWhatever
{
    static D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vertexFormat[];

};
```

D3DWhatever.cpp

```
D3DWhatever::D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vertexFormat[] =
{
{0,  0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION,0},
{0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD,0},
{0, 20, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_NORMAL,0},
{0, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TANGENT,  0},
{0, 44, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_BINORMAL, 0}, 
{1, 0,  D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 1},
{1, 16, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 2},
{1, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 3},
{1, 48, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 4},
 D3DDECL_END()
};
```